Design patterns for microservices and efficient handling of long-running tasks
I have developed a microservice in Python using bpy and Celery for rendering 3D models. I have questions regarding design patterns for such microservices and efficient handling of long-running tasks. Here are my specific questions:

What design patterns can be used in microservice development, especially for handling long-running tasks that may take several hours?

How can I efficiently manage the process of rendering 3D models, including the ability to cancel the rendering?

How can I launch a separate process for rendering from the Celery process and monitor its execution?


I am not looking for ready-made code, but rather approaches and resources to help me understand these topics. I would appreciate any information on design patterns for microservices and efficient handling of long-running tasks. What recommendations and resources can you suggest for studying this topic?
